# Oracle Transactions Queries, Asp.net timer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, transactions, oracle10g

I have an asp.net/C# application and backend as oracle.
I need to use transactions. Below is the reqirement:

I have a table OrderDetails with columns as:
"OrderId" "Ordername" "OrderStatus"

All OrderNames are shown in front-end as radiobutton. Once radiobutton is checked, the status of that order should change to "In-Process" and on click of "Create Order" button on page, the status should change to "Booked".

But in case radio button is unchecked or the Window is Closed, the status should change to "Available".

Also, once radiobutton is checked, a timer should start in front-end. Timer duration should come from another table of backend. The Order can be kept "In-Process" only for that timer duration.

Any pointers on how I can achieve this functionality.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The requirements look good but where are you stuck, you need to specify some specific bottlenecks you are facing so that someone here could help you with that.

Comment: I have never written transations too. So if any pointers on where to start shall help. On how to synchronize it with timer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here' the basic outline:

1. Whenever, order is checked, you need to fire a AJAX request that would trigger setting order into in-process status.
2. Maintain a last-updated column in the order table that would now indicate time when order has moved into in-progress status.
3. The AJAX request from #1 should return the timer duration and last-updated time to front-end js so that a time indication can be given to user. (you need to adjust server date-time to front-end date-time using half of round-trip time)
4. If order is unchecked then AJAX request can be fired to change the order status back to Available.
5. Create Order button can trigger AJAX request (or traditional ASP.NET post-back) to mark status as booked.
6. Have a database job running sufficiently periodically so that in-progress orders can be flipped back to available based on time elapsed from last-updated. You may choose any other kind of scheduling (e.g. windows scheduler) to do the same clean-up.
7. #6 should handle window-close scenario but you can always try to trigger a request to do the clean-up in different window (minimized) before closing the original window.

AJAX in ASP.NET and updating Oracle database are pretty routing things and you should able to find a lot of information/tutorials on the web. Same for transactions - I would suggest using `TransactionScope` for easier handing of transactions.